# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] in 'service_account.py' for json-credential file when run from CMD-prompt

Tags: python, gspread

I have placed the credential json-file in the same directory as the python source code file (py3.10) and when I run my code from within Visual Code (run and debug) it works fine.

However, when I run the same code from the CMD-prompt (as admin in Win10) I get the following error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
"C:\Users\USER1\Documents\PythonScripts\Data from BT connected Soehnle scale.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER1\Documents\PythonScripts\Data from BT connected Soehnle 
  scale.py", line 7, in <module>
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('mydata-332216-96035fc855db.json', scope)
  File "C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages
  \oauth2client\service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name
  with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mydata-332216-96035fc855db.json'
```

I tried placing the json in:

```
C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages
  \oauth2client\
C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
```

but it (obviously) did not help.

What is going on?

Comment: I expect that your current working directory isn't what you expect.  My suggestion is to never rely on what the current directory is.  If you know that the file you want to read is in the same directory as your script, us that fact. Use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the absolute path of your script, and use that to build the path to your JSON file.

Comment: Yes u r rite. Thanx solved now.

Answer (score 1):

When using gspread you don't need to handle the service account auth yourself.

You have helper functions for that: `gspread.service_account()`.

From there you simply need to place your service account file next to your code and give the relative path as follow:
`client = gspread.service_account("./my-sc.json")`

If you look at gspread documentation you'll notice that you can also place the file in the défaut config directory of your computer and gspread will find it.

> By default:
>
> - `%APPDATA%\gspread` on Windows
> - `~/.config/gspread` everywhere

So once you placed your service account credentials file in the folder you can simply authenticate using:
`gspread.service_account()`

And it will find your creds in the above folder.